# My face in my Japan visa is different because of my wisdom tooth extraction

Tags: visas, japan, photography

I'm worried about my photo in my Japan visa that was recently been printed. We applied last December 2018 with a bump of my face. My mother wanted to apply already so i quickly take a photo while my right side face is swelling because of my wisdom tooth extraction. And now my visa has been approved but I am still worried if they will suspect me of anything. Will the immigration officer question me about my face? We will be traveling next month Feb 2019. I am saving my medical certificate in case of emergency. And some pics while I have the swell.

Comment: Do no worry. Immigration officer are trained to recognize faces from photos, from traits which will not change. Usually we tend to check overall face, but this is not how immigration officer works (and and easy to change with make up). Maybe they will check closer, but if you didn't have a heavy plastic surgery, they will recognize you.

Answer (score 6):

No need to worry.

Passport checking officials can see that you had a bump on your face when the photo was taken (and likely only on one side) and that the bump is now gone.
They are trained to look at details that do not change and also trained to ignore things that can easily be changed.

If they wonder you can explain you had a tooth taken out.